# Присвоить высоту элемента в зависимости от другого?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не понимаю как правильно растянуть блок, который должен зависеть от блока, который находится внутри.

HTML разметка:

```
<div class="list-group-item block-panel stan">
    <div class="block item-7"></div>
</div>
```

присвоить высоту такую же я пытаюсь следующим образом:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list-group-item.block-panel.stan').height($('.block.item-7').height);
});
```

Но почему-то это не работает.
Может потому что блоки появляются не при загрузке страницы, а уже после каких-либо действий на странице? К слову эти элементы находятся в частичном представлении, которое загружается на страницу по клику кнопки. Если так, то как правильно достучаться до этих элементов и присвоить им одинаковую высоту?

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

UPD: дополню, что внутри блок имеет разную высоту, она не строго определенная, а каждый раз разная

Comment: если появляются по клику, а код этот срабатывает при загрузке страницы, то никакого влияния на них он, конечно, не окажет. более важный вопрос, почему вы пытаетесь сделать это средствами js а не css

Comment: Потому что блок внутри имеет динамическую высоту, а не строгую, каждый раз этот блок может иметь разную высоту, поэтому для меня оптимальный вариант это js, upd: спасибо, что указали о необходимости дополнить вопрос

Comment: а внешний блок у вас фиксированную высоту что ли имеет или что? что ему мешает растягиваться вместе со внутренним-то?

Comment: да, в css block-panel имеет фиксированную высоту на данный момент

Comment: убирал высоту в элемента в css, но это не сработало и сам он не растягивается в зависимости от элемента внутри

Comment: и зачем же делать фиксированную высоту элементу, у которого динамический контент? минимальную еще ладно, но фиксировать не ясно зачем. короче говоря дело ваше, хотите городить костыль, делайте пересчет, когда меняются данные в блоке. а если без костыля - делайте нефиксированный блок.

Comment: дак может надо задать ему `overflow` свойство, например, если сам не растягивается?

Comment: @teran Товарищ, используйте ваш комментарий как ответ, наводка мне помогла и решила мою проблему, установил высота элемента нефиксированной!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для растягивания родительского элемента уберите фиксированную высоту и добавьте `overflow:hidden`. В данной задаче JS не требуется.